# Silverstripe OrientDB

Tags: mysql, orientdb, silverstripe

I have started to learn how the CMS System Silverstripe works, because it uses OrientDB.
The moment I was installing it, there was asked me what database I used. My answer was MySQL.
SS created a MySQL database for me.

I'm really confused about it, because I taught it wouldn't use MySQL but OrientDB. So for me it looks that SS doesn't use OrientDB. Or is it possible that SS shall use OrientDB in the future? So does anybody can give me the name of a book that explains Silverstripe or can someone give me a basic explanation of it?

Thank you very much all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infrastructure requirements page for Silverstripe (http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/server-requirements) clearly calls for MySQL, PostgreSQL, or MS SQL Server.

The integration between [Silverstripe](http://www.silverstripe.org/) and [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/) appears to be a [work in progress](http://www.silverstripe.org/blog/no-more-joins-silverstripe-and-orientdb/).